# Looking for a supplier of card framed photographs

Tags: printing, prints

I have noticed quite a few stalls/shops in London sell their photo prints. The prints are usually backed and framed by white cardboard.

Can anyone suggest a print supplier who prints photos and packages them in this sort of format? I have been wanting to sell my photography for a while and I really like how these prints are presented.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Thanks
Oliver

Comment: There may not be a service that does this for you and if there is it's unlikely to be cost effective. I expect that most photographers selling their work prepare their own.

Comment: So would it be best to buy a kit as mentioned below? If so does anyone know of any in the UK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is more commonly called a "matted" or "mounted" print.  "Card framed" seems to be a British term.

Several labs in the U.S. will sell you a matted print, and I'd imagine some in the U.K. do, too.  The problem is that if you intend to sell your work, the cost of a lab-mounted print gets prohibitive.  As an example, one lab here sells an 8x10" print matted to 11x14" for US$22.

Matting your own prints is easy, and a quick trip to your favorite search engine will net you dozens of tutorials on how it's done.  I buy the show kits that dpollitt mentioned in his answer.  That plus the mounting tape and the print runs me about US$7 for the supplies to make a mounted and bagged print, or about a third of what a lab charges.  I also figure in some amount for my labor to assemble it, which still puts me well below the lab's price.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be exactly what I was after. I wasn't sure of the name of the print so I just mentioned that they were framed.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding what you are looking for right, you are just looking for a kit that sells matting, backing board, and clear/poly bags? If you could provide an image of an example that would help a great deal. At any rate would something like this work?

- http://www.clearbags.com/mats-backing/show-kits

Sorry I don't know what "card framed" means exactly.

Comment: That is similar to the sort of thing I am after. The photos tend to be centred against the board and sometimes they are bagged up.